# Python Scrapy stops at first element csspath() and doesn't scrape the rest

Tags: python, scrapy

I am simply trying to **scrape** multiple items from Bestbuy and Scrapy stops after the first item. Maybe I need to take a break and step away but I was wondering if anyone can spot why the for-loop stops after one iteration. Thanks for your help. Below is my script:

```
import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver


class InstockGPU(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "BestBuyGPU"
    start_urls = [ 
            'https://www.bestbuy.com/site/computer-cards-components/video-graphics-cards/abcat0507002.c?id=abcat0507002&qp=gpusv_facet%3DGraphics%20Processing%20Unit%20(GPU)~NVIDIA%20GeForce%20RTX%202060%5Egpusv_facet%3DGraphics%20Processing%20Unit%20(GPU)~NVIDIA%20GeForce%20RTX%202080%5Egpusv_facet%3DGraphics%20Processing%20Unit%20(GPU)~NVIDIA%20GeForce%20RTX%203060%5Egpusv_facet%3DGraphics%20Processing%20Unit%20(GPU)~NVIDIA%20GeForce%20RTX%203060%20Ti%5Egpusv_facet%3DGraphics%20Processing%20Unit%20(GPU)~NVIDIA%20GeForce%20RTX%203070%5Egpusv_facet%3DGraphics%20Processing%20Unit%20(GPU)~NVIDIA%20GeForce%20RTX%203080%5Egpusv_facet%3DGraphics%20Processing%20Unit%20(GPU)~NVIDIA%20GeForce%20RTX%203090%5Esoldout_facet%3DAvailability~Exclude%20Out%20of%20Stock%20Items',
    ]   


    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.css('ol.sku-item-list')    
        searched_items = {}
        count = -1
        for result in page:
            item = { 
                'title': result.css('div.sku-title h4.sku-header a::text').get(),

                'sku': result.css('div.sku-attribute-title span.sku-value::text').extract()[1],
                'price':  result.css('div.priceView-hero-price.priceView-customer-price span::text').extract()[0],
                'in-stock': False,
            }   
            # Check if stock
            if(result.css('button.btn::text').get()[1] == "Sold Out"):
               item['in-stock'] = True
            count += 1
            searched_items[count] = item
            yield searched_items
```

Comment: I figured out my problem and it was a simple one. <code>page</code> is an iterable where page[n] gets nth gpu title from list off items from ol.sku-item-list . I was used to BeautifulSoup4 but Scrapy is something I am still learning. Now I can get the fifth GPU listing from page[4].css('div.sku-title h4.sku-header a::text').get() which is 'GIGABYTE - NVIDIA GeForce RTX 30XX AORUS MASTER [X]GB GDDR6 PCI Express 4.0 Graphics Card' . I don't have enough votes to flag my post as non-relevant.

Comment: FYI it’s __scrape__ not scrap. To scrap means to throw away like rubbish.

Answer (score 0):

You probably wanted to iterate on the items and not the item-list.

```
page = response.css('ol.sku-item-list .sku-item')
```

Comment: Here is the output w/o your input:
```
{0: {'title': 'NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080 10GB GDDR6X PCI Express 4.0  Graphics Card - Titanium and Black', 'sku': '6429440', 'price': '$699.99', 'in-stock': False}}
```

with your input:
```
crawl_1  |     'sku': result.css('div.sku-attribute-title span.sku-value::text').extract()[1],
crawl_1  | IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: You should learn how to debug your code. You can not use `extract()` after `::text` selector.

Comment: response.css('div.sku-attribute-title span.sku-value::text').extract()[1] gives me '6429442' which is exactly what I want. Don't understand why I should debug what works when my issue/question was unrelated.